# scripts option is missing from iterm2 menu

Tags: python, iterm2

I wish to learn some python scripting for iterm2 with this [tutorial](https://iterm2.com/python-api/tutorial/index.html#tutorial-index).

However, the "Scripts" menu option does not exist, while all the other options do [exist](https://iterm2.com/documentation-menu-items.html).

Any suggestion? Maybe I should place an initial script in some directory?

Comment: maybe to see this menu you have to create folder for scripts like in [Running a Script](https://iterm2.com/python-api/tutorial/running.html) and put some script in this folder.

Comment: actually, `$HOME/Library/ApplicationSupport/iTerm2/Scripts` folder didn't exist on my machine. Created, added a script, restarted, but it didn't work

Comment: I don't use Mac so I can't help you.

Comment: Its available from only versions >=3.3.0